# Displaying sub-totals on each listview row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to display a sub-total of the database value bound to each row of my `ListView`. I don't want to keep the sub-total as a database column, so I am trying to accumulate the values as they are displayed.  Of course this brings up the obvious problems of how to deal with scrolling, which will display and re-display a value, messing up the running sub-total.

To elaborate, each listview row has two fields, a value and a sub-total.  The value comes from a database row, the sub-total is the total of all database rows up to and including that row. I don't want to include the sub-total into the database row if I don't have to, because that would make inserting and deleting rows more difficult.

Any ideas?

Comment: how is the sub-total calculated?

Comment: It is a running total.  Think of it as a checkbook, where the database rows contain the check amount, but not the balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom adapter, create an array to hold the subtotal and use that in your getView to maintain your subtotal even when scrolled.

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Cursor c;
private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private int[] subtotal;
private int subtotalhold;
private int layout;

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    this.c = c;
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = (Activity) context;
    this.layout = layout;

    subtotal = new int[c.getCount()];
    subtotalhold=0;
    c.moveToFirst();
    int i = 0;
    while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
        subtotalhold = subtotalhold + c.getInt(columnIndex);
        subtotal[i] = subtotalhold;
        i++;
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = View.inflate(context, layout, null);
    c.moveToPosition(position);

    TextView subtotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtotal);
            subtotal.setText(subtotal[position]);

            // rest of your code to populate the list row
    return (row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Barak, thanks for your answer.  I had also considered this approach, but the number of potential rows in the database could require a large array of floats or doubles, and I don't know how good an idea it is to use that kind of memory.  I still may go this way, but I am investigating another approach.

Comment: I'm gonna give this answer the bump because I decided to use it at least for the interim so that I can continue development.  Any other suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the values that are being loaded into the ListView and then calculate it at the same time...

Comment: That's what I do, but the same database entry gets loaded every time it is scrolled out of view and back into view, causing the accumulator to be incorrect.

Comment: Then change your Layout, so that the TextView doesn't go out of the screen. Basically anchor it to the bottom.

Comment: I don't think you understand.  I have edited my original question to make it clearer (I hope).

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to have a subtotal by adding each individual row, just have a final subtotal, its a waste of UI presence. Less information wtih a final conclusion is far better than bits and pieces on the UI and then a final value.

Comment: My intention is to simulate an old-school checkbook register.  The most common style is/was to subtract the new check from the previous balance and show the new balance.  The result is that each check entry has the then-current balance. Somehow comforting for us old guys, but a b**** to implement, apparently.

Comment: its not that hard, your approach is just causing it to get updated incorrectly, try posting some code and then further diagnosis can take place.